# SQL only can insert 1 Data

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Hello I have a problem with my SQL code and I don't know what's the cause. Below is my code:

```
//Sanitize the POST values
    $appdate = clean($con, $_POST['appdate']);
    $apptime = clean($con, $_POST['apptime']);
    $topic = clean($con, $_POST['topic']);
    $evaluation = clean($con, $_POST['evaluation']);
    $counselor = clean($con, $_POST['counselor']);
    $desc = clean($con, $_POST['desc']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO appointment VALUES(NULL, '$memid', '$counselor', '$appdate', '$apptime', '$topic', '$evaluation', '$desc', 'Pending')";
    $test=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($test) {
        header("location: main.php?page=appointments");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Query failed.";
        exit();
    }
```

The problem is, I only can insert 1 data only to the table. The next data can't be inserted inside the table, it will show "query failed". It is confusing to me. Can someone helps me.

p/s: sorry for bad grammar/english

Comment: Did you try to remove the NULL ? Why is it there?

Comment: When you execute the same query in MySQL client does it work?

Comment: @Kangoo13 It's for my auto increment id, should I just remove it?

Comment: @bhelmet yeah, the same query. But the second try will shows query failed. The data is not inserted into the table.

Comment: Yes remove it and tell me what happens now

Comment: Can you show your table structure?
Which unique indexes you have in table?

Comment: @Kangoo13 Still the same, query failed.

Comment: Refer to the linked answer, check for the *actual* mysql error and then fix it.

Comment: @bhelmet Here's the screenshot. http://imgur.com/2qQQoN4

Comment: @YourCommonSense actual mysql error? btw, it will not insert if there is data inside the table. If there is no data inside the table, the query will insert the data.

Comment: You have to understand that if something doesn't work, then there is **always** an error message with explanation, why it is so. All you need is to get that error message and read what it says. As simple as that. No need for wild guesses. No need for trial and error. No need tor speculations of any sort. Just get the error message and read it.